# What is base price of a security?

Tags: terminology, security

What is the difference between the *Base Price of Security* and the *Face Value of Security*?

Comment: This might be clearer with an example.  Are you reading this in an application?  Perhaps give an example security that has a different base price and face value.

Comment: I have only heard of Par Value of a stock.

Comment: _Par Value of Stock_ and _Face Value of Stock_ are same.

Answer (score 1):

The base price is the one you paid when you initiated the position.

Face value is the value stated by the issuer. Although it may apply to stocks, it's most relevant for bonds. It the latter's case, it's the value you will get at maturity when they are redeemed.

Here's an example

```
Buying 10 2years zero interest bonds @950$ with 100$ of fees with a face value of 1000$
Base price of position : 9500$  (950$ x 10)
Cost basis of position : 9600$  (9500$+100$)
Face value of position : 10000$ (1000$ x 10)

YTM of bond :     2.60%
YTM of position : 2.06%
```